# How to display IGeometry?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I've done an intersection with the ITopologicalOperator6 interface, and I now have an IGeometry with the result.

How to draw this in a graphics layer on the map? I want to see what was intersected (possibly colored).

According to this topic: [CustomLayer Draw Com Exception](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2550/customlayer-draw-com-exception)

it seems that I could create a new layer from the IMap interface.. is this possible? Is there any other more convenient way to do this?

How would you draw an IGeometry item to your map?

Comment: The topic you link to applies to arcengine - not arcgis server.  Since the web adf is slated for retirement, have you considered using the [REST Geometry Service](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/geometryserver.html) instead?

Comment: I don't like adf neither, but I have a work where I should fix something with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw to the GraphicsLayer http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ADF/graphics.htm

Comment: I can't use this code without some conversion (which I don't know how to do). Look at the 'fglayer.Add(point);' line, it accepts a web.adf.geometry point not a IGeometry point, how to convert from IGeometry to a web adf Geometry??

Comment: Look at Geometry Examples section here http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ADF/conversion.htm

Comment: Thank you! Your links (which I could not find.. maybe I can't search properly) solved my problems!